# What does 変わっていく mean in this case?

Tags: nuances

I was listening to a podcast, and the lady talking was discussing new year resolutions. Then I heard the following phrase:

> 私は毎年考えるんだけど、考えるもやっぱり通りにはできない。いろいろ**変わっていく**からね。

I am a beginner but I have a rough understanding of what she is saying:

> I think about it every year, however, every time I cant do them (the new year resolutions).
> This is from a variety of **"changes"**.

What does いく have to do here? Also, please feel free to fix my translation if it is wrong.

Comment: Edit: 変わったいく should be in bold. Same applies to "Changes"

Comment: You mean 変わっていく not 変わったいく, right?

Comment: Correct, 変わっていく

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant to write 変わっていく, I think the nuance here is a bit difficult to capture in direct English translation.

The general idea is that things are constantly changing throughout the year.

If you just said 変わった, that would mean, "it changed".

If you said 変わる, that would mean, "it will change".

It would seem the speaker wants to say that *circumstances* (she doesn't use this word) change over the year.  And that's perhaps why keeping one's resolutions is a challenge.

変わっていく captures this notion that things will continue to change.

Comment: "It would seem the speaker wants to say that circumstances (she doesn't use this word) change over the year" I believe you are right, she continued after the sentence I posted by saying:

"やっぱり目標も仕事も生活も、変わっていくんですよ"

Comment: @Micheal I think that follow up sentence nicely illustrates further exactly this very notion.